# Makefile for dotfiles (graphviz)

Tags: makefile

As part of generating a PDF from a latex file, I got a makefile from [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40759/114245).

```
# You want latexmk to *always* run, because make does not have all the info.
# Also, include non-file targets in .PHONY so they are run regardless of any
# file of the given name existing.
.PHONY: paper-1.pdf all clean

# The first rule in a Makefile is the one executed by default ("make"). It
# should always be the "all" rule, so that "make" and "make all" are identical.
all: paper-1.pdf

# CUSTOM BUILD RULES

# In case you didn't know, '$@' is a variable holding the name of the target,
# and '$<' is a variable holding the (first) dependency of a rule.
# "raw2tex" and "dat2tex" are just placeholders for whatever custom steps
# you might have.

%.tex: %.raw
    ./raw2tex $< > $@

%.tex: %.dat
    ./dat2tex $< > $@

# MAIN LATEXMK RULE

# -pdf tells latexmk to generate PDF directly (instead of DVI).
# -pdflatex="" tells latexmk to call a specific backend with specific options.
# -use-make tells latexmk to call make for generating missing files.

# -interaction=nonstopmode keeps the pdflatex backend from stopping at a
# missing file reference and interactively asking you for an alternative.

paper-1.pdf: paper-1.tex
    latexmk -bibtex -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make paper-1.tex

clean:
    latexmk -bibtex -CA
```

My figures are .dot files that I turn into PNG files. I can make the PNGs with some basic shell commands, but that it doesn't make sense to use a shell script because you lose the advantages of `make`.

Here's what I've been trying after reading some documentation.

```
%.png: %.dot
    dot -Tpng $(.SOURCE) -o $(.TARGET)
```

and

```
.dot.png:
    dot -Tpng $(.SOURCE) -o $(.TARGET)
```

However, whenever I try to run the target directly the terminal prints is:

```
dot -Tpng  -o
```

and it holds because it waits for input from STDIN because there was no input file.

If I try to invoke the rule by running `make *.dot` I get the output:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `figure-1a.dot'.
make: Nothing to be done for `figure-1b.dot'.
```

I'm clearly not understanding what I need to do. How do I get the makefile to take all the .dot files and create .png files every time I run through the creation of the PDF?

UPDATE: Here is another attempt I tried

```
graphs := $(wildcard *.dot)
.dot.png: $(graphs)
    dot -Tpng $(.SOURCE) -o $(.TARGET).png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU make uses `$<` and `$@`, not `.SOURCE` and `.TARGET`, the recipe should be

```
.PHONY: all

all: $(patsubst %.dot,%.png,$(wildcard *.dot))

%.png: %.dot
    dot -Tpng $< -o $@
```

Comment: `.SOURCE` and `.TARGET` were from something I read online (the source escapes me now, but it doesn't matter if it's wrong)

How do I invoke the rule?

Comment: @BCqrstoO Updated.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was more than somewhat lost, I appreciate it!

Comment: You deserve many more upvotes than you have